# Undocumented SmoScriptOption: ScriptForAlter and ScriptForCreateDrop

Tags: sql-server, smo

1. scrp.Options.ScriptForAlter -- I suppose it scripts an `ALTER TABLE` instead of a `CREATE TABLE`
2. scrp.Options.ScriptForCreateDrop -- I'd guess it scripts a `DROP TABLE` and only afterwards a `CREATE TABLE` ?

My DB is fairly large and I'm still using Management Studio for script generation, so I'd like to know if someone else already found out the meaning of those options.

Comment: You could always try testing and see the results. You can self-answer a question here.

Comment: AFAICT, they are no-ops.